# C# excel SaveAs file could not be accessed when saving

Tags: c#, excel, csv, save-as

Attempting to save an excel worksheet programmatically as a unique filename in a loop.

```
    private static DateTime csvtime = DateTime.Now;
    private static string time = csvtime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    private static string Path = @"C:\users\User\desktop\MonetaryEntry_"+time+".csv";
    mySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myBook.Worksheets[1];


mySheet.SaveAs(Path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
```

This fails with the following error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in MonetaryEntryFormatting.exe
>
> Additional information: The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:
>
> • Make sure the specified folder exists.
>
> • Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.
>
> • Make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or  *
>
> • Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.

however when I change the Path string to

```
private static string path = "@C:\users\user\desktop\MonetaryEntry_.csv";
```

it resolves.

The goal is to iterate through a loop saving each time as a unique *.csv file. Undetermined amount of .csv files will be generated each time.

a few notes;

writing to the desktop the user account I'm currently doing all the work in. If relevant, I copy a file on the desktop and paste as a different name and work from there.

I feel I might be missing something fairly simple as this kind of issue typically is..

Comment: You cannot have `:` in a file name, use another character in your format string.

Comment: Its unlikely, if your looping, that each time value will be unique each cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static DateTime csvtime = DateTime.Now;
private static string time = csvtime.ToString("HH_mm_ss");
private static string Path = @"C:\users\User\desktop\MonetaryEntry_"+time+".csv";
mySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myBook.Worksheets[1];
mySheet.SaveAs(Path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
```

this is going to work change the tostring.   the `:` is not a character allowed in the path.   (look at the 3rd suggestion of the error)

Comment: Wow I feel duuuumb. Thanks!